# What is this way of solving differential equations is called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation given by:
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = D \nabla^2 p$$
where $p$ is bounded by one initial condition and two boundary condition. We need to find out $p$, a function of $r$ and $t$; $D$ is constant.The approach used [**here**](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/NSM.pdf) page 54  is to partition $p$ like: $$p=u+v$$ where both $u$ and $v$ satisfies one initial and one boundary condition individually. But one boundary condition is just satisfied by only $v$. We solve for both of them individually and then add the results.
What way is this to solve differential equation and when it is helpful?
Can somebody please elaborate to me?

Comment: This follows by linearity (in fact, here just additivity) of the differential operators, $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ and $ \nabla^2,$ and the pointwise definition of the sum of two functions. It's the pointwise definition of the sum of two functions that takes care of the initial and boundary conditions --- the value of $p$ at some input is the sum of the values of $u$ and $v$ at the same input.

Comment: The Principle of Superposition.

Comment: It is useful for linear equations, since a linear combination of solutions is still a solution.

Comment: @Nick Do both $u$ and $v$ need to satisfy initial condition or the partition can be irrespective of boundary and initial conditions?